# Ckeditor 4 uploadimage plugin not changing Image Src after it is uploaded

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

CKEDITOR 4 is not changing default Image src after uploaded successfully by server.

Server responding with proper JSON format as per Ckeditor document. Looks like `{"uploaded":1,"url":"test.gif","fileName":"test.gif"}`

Ckeditor initiated looks like bellow

`let editorInstanse=CKEDITOR.replace('txtEditor',{ extraPlugins: 'uploadimage', uploadUrl: '/brochure/uploadImage' });`